# Launching the Notes app subsequently launches the Calendar App as well

Tags: macos, calendar, notes.app

Whenever I launch the Notes app, the Calendar app launches as well. I use the Notes app a lot and this can be very frustrating. I updated to High Sierra 10.13.5 to see if it would solve the problem, to no success. When calendar opens it asks something about subscribing to a calendar. The message is shown [image: here.]I am on an iMac.

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: In Terminal, what happens when you execute the command `open /Applications/Notes.app`?

Comment: @IconDaemon  Same thing. Two or three seconds after launching Notes, the Calendar icon in the dock starts bouncing and then the Calendar appears.  Thanks.

Comment: Has this always happened? If not, do you remember anything that you did on the Mac (update/upgrade macOS, install software, etc,) after which this started happening? Is Notes connected to your iCloud account?

Comment: This started maybe 9-10 months ago. I've had the computer for years.  I've tried to recall something I may have done to cause it but no luck.  Yes, Notes is connected to my iCloud account.  I've updated my post to show the screen that appears when Calendar opens. Maybe that provides a clue. Thank you.

Comment: Could one of the notes saved in Notes.app have this calendar URL inside it? Perhaps this is causing Calendar to open? Just a wild guess.

Comment: Holy cow you were right on!!  I found a note that had the link. I deleted the note and now things are back to normal.  If you want to write this up as an answer I'll accept it!  Thank you a thousand times. I appreciate your help...

Comment: Sometimes wild guesses are the best!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should check to see if there is a webcal URL in a note somewhere in Notes.app.

If there is, Notes will open Calendar.app and ask you to subscribe. If you don't actually want to subscribe to this calendar, just delete the webcal URL in the note (or delete the note entirely) and Calendar should not open again.